# Why isnt the rest of the numbers in the correlation matrix present?

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation

I'm trying to display a correlation matrix but for some reason only the first row of numbers is outputing, not every single row, it makes no sense because in another persons code, [his works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8ZVI.png)

```
corr_matrix=df.corr()
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax=sns.heatmap(corr_matrix,annot=True,linewidths=0.5,fmt='.2f',cmap='YlGnBu')
```

Comment: It's a known bug.